# How can I add data points to my line plot in same colour (matplotlib)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a line plot to which I would like to add original datapoints in the same colour as the lines (which are fine in default). Problem: When I do it for a lot of IDs or datapoints (also missings) I can no longer distinguish to whom that data belong.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['1988', '1989', '1990', '1988', '1989', '1990', '1988', '1989', '1990'],
                   'id': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3'],
                   'money': ['5', '7', '8', '8', '3', '3', '7', '8', '10']}).astype(int)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in df.id.unique():
    df[df['id']==i].plot.line(x='year', y='money', ax=ax, label='id = %s'%i)
    df[df['id']==i].plot.scatter(x='year', y='money', ax=ax)
    plt.xticks(np.unique(df.year))
```

[image]

Question: How can I access the default color list of my `plot.line` to use it in `plot.scatter`? Or is there another, easier way to highlight the data which constitutes the lines?

Comment: pass `c='r'` into `.plot.scatter`?

Comment: This will change everything from all-blue in all-red. I need the same colours as given by plot.line default to distinguish my cases. regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `marker` option in `plot.line`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in df.id.unique():
    df[df['id']==i].plot.line(x='year', 
                              y='money', 
                              marker='o', # this add the data points on the line, with the same color 
                              ax=ax, 
                              label='id = %s'%i)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The marker is not shown in the first two legend entries?

Comment: @Sheldore Interestingly, no. They only show with a call of `plt.legend()`. A bug maybe?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can try, although @QuangHoang is the better solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['1988', '1989', '1990', '1988', '1989', '1990', '1988', '1989', '1990'],
                   'id': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3'],
                   'money': ['5', '7', '8', '8', '3', '3', '7', '8', '10']}).astype(int)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

color = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']

for i in df.id.unique():
    df[df['id']==i].plot.line(x='year', y='money', ax=ax, label='id = %s'%i)
    df[df['id']==i].plot.scatter(x='year', y='money', ax=ax, color=color[i-1])
    plt.xticks(np.unique(df.year))
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Good to know how to access the color sequence. Although, the `color=color[i-1]` only works if `df.id.unique() == (1,2,3)` like this special case.

Comment: Yes,  That is true, it is better to use enumerate.